# Mono Sqlite3 - sqlite3 module not found

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono

I'm working on a project that's making use of sqlite using the Mono.Data.Sqlite dll so that my program is cross platform on Windows and mono. The program successfully builds without any issues but then when I run the program, and it tries to make a connection to the database.

However, I am getting an error

> Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Below is the code for how I am connecting to the SQLite database

```
public SqliteConnection conn = null;
        private static string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        private static string exeName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
        public static string DATABASE_PATH = path + string.Format("\\BoardiesITSolutions\\{0}\\{0}.db", exeName);

        public ConnectSQLiteDatabase(string dbPassword)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DB Password: {0}", Encryption.decrypt(dbPassword));
                conn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source="+DATABASE_PATH+";Password="+Encryption.decrypt(dbPassword));
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (SqliteException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Open Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I think you will likely have to use the Windows interop (Win32 compiled SQLite) library when running on Windows. The .NET code may be cross platform but the SQLite binary is probably not. File format the same, yes, but binary executable, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve the issue.

I installed the precompiled binaries for Windows and imported that DLL into my project so its working fine on windows. Then downloaded the source and manually built the DLL for mono from the link http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/build.wiki#mono and install this on the linux server and it works fine on both platforms now.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```